# Get a parameter from a rewritten URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a url parameter using javascript so i can pass the paramter to google maps

The problem is i'm using mod rewrite on the url

> www.mysite.com/1/my-event

instead of

> www.mysite.com/mypage.php?id=1&name=my-event

I've tried doing an alert but it comes up blank

Here is the javascript function that **will** work if i don't rewrite the url

```
function gup( name ){
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if( results == null )
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
```

Comment: JS works on the client side. The url it has to work with is the URL you see in the address bar. The server-side rewrite with the query parameters is NOT visible to JS, unless the server-side rewrite forces a client redirect to the rewritten url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rewritten format, with the query-string, isn't available to your JavaScript.

You'll have to grab the value out of `location.pathname` (`/1/my-event` in your example), instead:

```
var params = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(1); // ["1", "my-event"]

var id = params[0];
var name = params[1];
```

Comment: Thanks...i found something similar a minute ago

Answer (score 1):

Just split the URL on `/` characters and take the last elements in the resulting array, mapping them to the names you expect.

Comment: Use JS's string `split()` function.